# Split a string into a list, leaving accented chars and emoticons but removing punctuation

Tags: python, string, split, emoticons

If i have the string:

```
"O João foi almoçar :) ."
```

how do i best split it into a list of words in python like so:

```
['O','João', 'foi', 'almoçar', ':)']
```

?

Thanks :)

Sofia

Comment: How do you distinguish between punctuation and emoticons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the punctuation falls into its own space-separated token as with your example, then it's easy:

```
>>> filter(lambda s: s not in string.punctuation, "O João foi almoçar :) .".split())
['O', 'Jo\xc3\xa3o', 'foi', 'almo\xc3\xa7ar', ':)']
```

If this is not the case, you can define a dictionary of smileys like this (you'll need to add more):

```
d = { ':)': '<HAPPY_SMILEY>', ':(': '<SAD_SMILEY>'}
```

and then replace each instance of the smiley with the place-holder that doesn't contain punctuation (we'll consider `<>` not to be punctuation):

```
for smiley, placeholder in d.iteritems():
    s = s.replace(smiley, placeholder)
```

Which gets us to `"O João foi almoçar <HAPPY_SMILEY> ."`.

We then strip punctuation:

```
s = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c not in '.,!', list(s)))
```

Which gives us `"O João foi almoçar <HAPPY_SMILEY>"`.

We do revert the smileys:

```
for smiley, placeholder in d.iteritems():
    s = s.replace(placeholder, smiley)
```

Which we then split:

```
s = s.split()
```

Giving us our final result: `['O', 'Jo\xc3\xa3o', 'foi', 'almo\xc3\xa7ar', ':)']`.

Putting it all together into a function:

```
def split_special(s):
    d = { ':)': '<HAPPY_SMILEY>', ':(': '<SAD_SMILEY>'}
    for smiley, placeholder in d.iteritems():
        s = s.replace(smiley, placeholder)
    s = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c not in '.,!', list(s)))
    for smiley, placeholder in d.iteritems():
        s = s.replace(placeholder, smiley)
    return s.split()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import string
>>> [ i for i in s.split(' ') if i not in string.punctuation]
['O', 'João', 'foi', 'almoçar', ':)']
```

Comment: ['O', 'Jo\xc6o', 'foi', 'almo\x87ar', ':)']