# Python coding test problem for interviews

Tags: python

I'm trying to come up with a good coding problem to ask interview candidates to solve with Python.

They'll have an hour to work on the problem, with an IDE and access to documentation (we don't care what people have memorized).

**I'm not looking for a tough algorithmic problem** - there are other sections of the interview where we do that kind of thing. The point of this section is to sit and watch them actually write code. So it should be something that makes them use just the data structures which are the everyday tools of the application developer - lists, hashtables (dictionaries in Python), etc, to solve a quasi-realistic task. They shouldn't be blocked completely if they can't think of something really clever.

We have a problem which we use for Java coding tests, which involves reading a file and doing a little processing on the contents. It works well with candidates who are familiar with Java (or even C++). But we're running into a number of candidates who just don't know Java or C++ or C# or anything like that, but do know Python or Ruby. Which shouldn't exclude them, but leaves us with a dilemma: On the one hand, we don't learn much from watching someone struggle with the basics of a totally unfamiliar language. On the other hand, **the problem we use for Java turns out to be pretty trivial in Python (or Ruby, etc)** - anyone halfway competent can do it in 15 minutes. So, I'm trying to come up with something better.

Surprisingly, Google doesn't show me anyone doing something like this, unless I'm just too dumb to enter the obvious search term. The best idea I've come up with involves scheduling workers to time slots, but it's maybe a little too open-ended. Have you run into a good example? Or a bad one? Or do you just have an idea?

Comment: Can't you let them do your Java question in Python?

Comment: @macrog He stated that the Java thing is really trivial in Python etc.

Comment: That's one of the things we do now. But it turns out to be too easy in Python.

Comment: @Ivo Missed that part. @Kal Can you tell us the Java question so we know the level you're looking at?

Comment: @marcog Hmm, I didn't want to say just in case somebody figures out where I work... basically they have to output a frequency count of the words in the file, but there's a twist that makes it a bit tougher.

Comment: I specially like "we don't care what people have memorized"

Comment: Check out this Python test, it's quite good: https://tests4geeks.com/python-online-test

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've asked candidates to write code to implement bowling scoring before, which is readily comprehensible but contains enough wrinkles that most people have to iterate their approach a couple times to cover all the edge cases.

A lot of the problems at http://www.streamtech.nl/site/problem+set, which are taken from ACM competitions, are also suitable for your use.  I used them to familiarize myself with python syntax and language features.  A lot amount to straightforward application of standard data structures; some are more focused on algorithmic issues.  If you sort through them I'm sure you'll find several that fit your needs.

Comment: Sadly that link is now dead. Old question I know, but still top so maybe select a different answer?

Comment: It's available on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130502164931/http://www.streamtech.nl/site/problem+set

Answer (score 5):

I can recommend to you [Checkio.org](http://checkio.org)

Answer (score 2):

You can always just give them a few more questions on top of the Java one, like ask them to do the Java task, then ask them to define a class, then ask them to do [FizzBuzz](http://imranontech.com/2007/01/24/using-fizzbuzz-to-find-developers-who-grok-coding/). That should be about as rigorous as your Java task.

Don't be afraid to ask a series of questions. Maybe you can even ask them to write a few one-liners to make sure they get the finer points of Python (write a list comprehension, how do you define a lambda, etc.)

Comment: +1 For list comprehensions, let them do FizzBuzz in a list comprehension, that can be done in under 2 minutes. And then some other non trivial comprehension stuff, or iterators and such.

Comment: That would make sense if this was a test of their knowledge of Python, but that's not the goal. We want to see a design, watch it evolve and get debugged, etc.

Comment: @Kal then asking them to define a class that did some file I/O might be a good idea.

Comment: I can literally do FizzBuzz with my eyes closed in python using emacs. It's super trivial

Comment: @Kal Well if you want have them to design something. Give them a more complex application barebone, tell them you want features X, Y and Z. Let them read the code (obviously shows you how long it takes them to understand the existing application), ask them how they are going to add the features to the existing code (shows you how they're thinking when it comes to extend existing code), you can then see how the interact with the code etc. Put in a bug or two in the existing source to have them debug it.

Comment: @Ivo - I think that would be a valid approach. I'd prefer something that's closer to what we do for Java (which works for us), but a priori, that's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [question I answered on SO recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535047/split-a-string-into-a-list-leaving-accented-chars-and-emoticons-but-removing-pun) that might be the start of something suitable:

> Given a string `"O João foi almoçar :)
>   ."`, split it into a list of words.
>   You must strip all punctuation except
>   for emoticons. Result for example:
>   `['O','João', 'foi', 'almoçar', ':)']`

I've tidied up the question a bit. See the original linked above along with my answer. It tests a number of things, and there are different ways of tackling the problem. They can also get a half-solution out that first disregards the emoticons and punctuation aspect. Just finding the emoticons is another sub-problem that can be solved separately. And so on...

You could extend it to asking about emoticons adjacent to other punctuation, adjacent emoticons, overlapping emoticons, defining emoticons in `:)` form but also searching for those of the form `:-)`. You could also turn it into a frequency count problem instead of just splitting to somewhat line up with your Java question.

I also suggest searching through the [python+interview-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions+python) questions posted on SO. There are some good ones, and you may even want to broaden your search to skim all [interview-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) posts if you have time.

Comment: That sounds close enough to our Java problem that I suspect it's going to be too easy unless the requirements get pretty complicated, which is not ideal.

Comment: @Kal Handling emoticons vs other punctuation can be made non-trivial if you plan the question well.

Comment: The tagged search (interview questions + python) returns nothing, as does interview quetions by itself. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Python specifically, but I found that interview questions which involve recursion are a very effective filter. I have asked candidates to produce all the permutations of a string (and think about how to test it), and I have been asked to pseudo-code the Longest Common Subsequence.

Comment: permutations of a string is built in in Python. Also, a good python programmer will, in many circumstances, prefer a non-recursive solution.